# How can you use a CSS grid with multiple items rendered by one React component?

Tags: css, reactjs

Currently I have some React render() code like this:

```
<div id='PhotoContainer'>

photoArray.map(....

...<PhotoItem />)

</div>
```

`<PhotoItem />` is a component which renders a single image based on an URL passed to it. photoArray is an array of URLs and the .map is used to render an instance of `<PhotoItem />` for every image in the array.

I have applied {display: grid} to #PhotoContainer in CSS so I can arrange the returned photos responsively in a grid, however it seems to be recognising `<PhotoItem />` as one item and assigning allll the photos to one grid area? Whereas I want one `<PhotoItem />` per grid area...

I want 4 photos per row, and the CSS code I am currently using is:

```
#PhotoContainer {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

But the items never wrap. The photos just keep being added forever and ever on the same line... and I assume, in the same grid area.

What am I missing?

I know I could potentially use flex, but I want the user to be able to choose how many photos per row they want, and passing in a new number to the grid-template-columns value seems like the easiest way if I can get it working...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML? We are missing most of the info to diagnose the problem. Please consider a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should work:

```js
const PhotoItem = ({ url }) =>
  <img src={ url } />

const PhotoContainer = ({ photoArray }) =>
  <div id="PhotoContainer">
    { photoArray.map(url =>
      <PhotoItem url={ url } />
    ) }
  </div>

const exampleUrl = 'https://placedog.net/100/100'
const photos = Array.from(new Array(10), () => exampleUrl)

ReactDOM.render(<PhotoContainer photoArray={ photos } />, document.body)
```

```css
#PhotoContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect there's something else going on with your code.

Comment: Thank you!! You triggered something and I realised that each image was within a ```<div>``` and that was messing things up! You have no idea how much this has bugged me!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you!